# Matlab hide imtool window

Tags: matlab

I'm using imtool in Matlab to do some things like finding circles in a large image. In my case it works better than imshow, cause I can load larger images without reduceing the resolution (which caused problems regarding to find specific circles). To speed up the program I wonder if I can hide the window which will open when I use imtool. In my case imshow didn't work (besides not showing it), cause it always changes the zoom to fit the picture according to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `imtool` (since you don't seem to need the tools), you can just manually specify the [`InitialMagnitifcation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#input_argument_namevalue_InitialMagnification) of `imshow` to prevent it from automatically scaling

```
imshow(data, 'InitialMagnification', 100)
```